# How to think about creating clipping masks?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, images, page-layout

I would like to receive perspectives about how to think about inserting pictures within an instagram post art. For example, I'm creating this post:
[image: instagram post art]

and I need to insert this picture:[image: photo I need to insert]

So I want to learn what factors are relevant for me to make a decent job, integrating the photo with the rest of the art, instead of just using a rectangular or circular shape mask (that's almost all of my inventary to accomplish that task).

Thank you very much!

Comment: You're asking this in a very vague and broad way... It's not very apparent what kinda answer you're looking for. "what factors are relevant" ← It's almost like you're writing a paper on the subject instead of looking for ways to actually do the job. The question would be easier to answer if it was along the lines of "How do I remove the background from this image". Although, that sorta question might get closed because this site and google have answered this question like a bazillion times.

Comment: For this image, I would use PS and a Layer Mask to remove the background. There's too much blurriness/cast shadow to bother doing it in AI. Even in PS, this would be challenging. Mostly because the back of the plate is basically invisible and the fork is missing like 1/3 of its width. I would expect those sections to look weird if there is any transparency on them when you place the image on above a colored background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be looking into "masking images in Photoshop with transitions"- you can have subtle transitions from the foreground image to the background image by "brushing into your mask" the transition areas. You are correct that a stark shape (rectangle or ellipse) outlining the foreground image, in this case, would not look so good.

As @Joonas said in the comments this would be easier done in Photoshop by masking your "food image" into your "background image".

Photoshop Example-

[image]

This is done by placing your "food image" on a layer above your "background image" and then creating a mask on the "food image" layer- then simply use the brush tool with a soft edge brush to paint back the areas you want to show

This can also be done in Illustrator but is more complicated. I achieved the following results using an "Opacity Mask" rather than a "Clipping Mask"- (Please see this excellent answer from @Scott to explain the difference between the two)

[How to edit clipping mask path after creating in illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/94028)

Illustrator Example-

[image]

I used a "free form gradient" to create the mask in the transparency panel- again, for this situation, this is a much easier task to perform in Photoshop

Comment: thank you very much for the answers !